# Como reutilizar uma String em um outro Step do meu teste?

Tags: java, testes, testes-automatizados, cucumber

estou com uma dúvida (talvez simples para a maioria) e precisava da ajuda de vocês...

Estou programando um Fluxo End-to-End de APIs utilizando Java, RestAssured e Cucumber (para definir meus steps).

Na minha primeira API é gerada um numero de proposta no retorno que é utilizada no body das outras APIs.

Como eu conseguiria capturar essa String em um Step do meu fluxo, e reutilizar nos demais Steps? alguem poderia me ajudar?

Sou grato pela ajuda desde já pessoal! :D

Answer (score 0):

Caique Pena,

Tente o seguinte:

1- Crie uma variável global;

2- popule a variavel com o valor que deseja;

3- reutilize em outro método;

```
public class Steps(){
    int idade;

    public void pegaIdade(){
         idade = 10;
    }

    public void reutilizaIdade(){
         int calculaSomaDeIdade = idade + 15;
    }
}
```

Abç.